# C incompatible types error when assigning to variable of same type

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, types

I have the following code:

```
typedef unsigned char some_type[6];

int main() {
        some_type some_var1;
        some_type some_var2;
        some_var1 = some_var2;
        return 0;
}
```

And when i try to compile it, I get the following error message:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type 'some_type' from type 'unsigned char *'
```

Why is this? Both variables are exactly the same type? What can I do to make it work? I can't change the typedef, as it is part of an API I am using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't assign arrays to each other like that. If these are strings, use strcpy:

```
strcpy(some_var1, some_var2);
```

If not, use memcpy:

```
memcpy(&some_var1, &some_var2, sizeof (some_type));
```

Answer (score 4):

Arrays can't be copied in that way. The usual way to copy arrays is by using `memcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign one array to the other because arrays decay to constant pointers. Besides, you probably wouldn't want to just copy the address of one array into the other variable. You'll need to use something like `memcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use memcpy for this as C doesn't really support copying of structures this way.

```
memcpy(&some_var1, &some_var2, sizeof(some_var));
```